# Profile Page Unauthorized (GET 401)

Tags: node.js, angular, rest

I'm trying to create a mean application, and I'm using JWT token for authentication.

The Get request for User Profile says It's unauthorized. But when I send the JWT token through postman, It gets authorized. I think there's a problem in my front-end Angular code.

I tried to console log ***this.authTokenStudent*** and ***this.loadToken()*** Both tokens are exactly the same and when I copy that token into postman, It gets authorized.

> This is my auth.service.ts File:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface data{
  success: boolean;
  msg: string;
  token: string;
  user: Object;
  teacher: any;
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  authTokenStudent: any;
  authTokenTeacher: any;
  user: any;
  teacher: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post<data>('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate/student', user, {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res);
  }

  getStudentProfile() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.authTokenStudent = this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authTokenStudent);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get<data>('http://localhost:3000/users/profile/student', {headers: headers})
    .map(res => res);
  }
  loadToken(){
    const studentToken = localStorage.getItem('student_id_token');
    return studentToken;
  }
}
```

> This is my profile.component.ts File:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  user: Object;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getStudentProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile.user;
      console.log(profile);
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }

}
```

The authenticate user in auth.service.ts works and Logs the user in, but displaying the profile info is not working due to the error: GET request 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add "bearer " + token for the authorization

like so:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders ({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.authTokenStudent}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
};

return this.http.get<data>('http://localhost:3000/users/profile/student', httpOptions).map(res => res);
```

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to be in the correct Case.   please make sure the header is actually sent in your browser

Comment: Tried this too, still not working. And how do I make sure that header is actually being sent in my browser?

Comment: CTRL-SHIFT-I  -> developer console in brrowser. there you have some form of network tab.  if you click on the request (if any) the you should find details

Comment: The POST request for Login, Response says success: true with the same token, but the GET request says unauthorized.

Comment: I think you headers were not passed correctly.  also for the get student profile link don't you need to pass some id?

Comment: I tried your edited version still unauthorized, and this code used to work before without an ID, after I upgraded my Angular-Cli this started happening.

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.  i'm sure this is working. don't know whats wrong with your version.  check step by step.  that's all I can say.

Comment: Its working now, Thanks alot for your help.

This is what i did:

    getStudentProfile(){
    
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders ({
            'Authorization': this.loadToken(),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }),
        };
        return this.http.get<data> 
    ('http://localhost:3000/users/profile/student', 
    httpOptions).map(res => res); 
      }